# Managed Direct3D: Lock entire Vertex Buffer

Tags: directx, direct3d, managed-directx

I have a `Mesh` object returned from `Mesh::TextFromFont` and I am trying to set the color of each vertex. I am calling the vertex buffer's `Lock` function like this:

mesh->VertexBuffer->Lock(0, LockFlags::None);

However, this call throws an exception. Another overload of `Lock` seems to work fine, however it requires me to pass the rank of the returned vertex array. What is the solution here? How do I lock the vertex buffer of a mesh returned from `TextFromFont`?

Comment: What is the exception you get?

Comment: VertexBuffer is probably NULL then.  Its worth noting that Managed DX is no longer supported.  You should probably use SlimDX or XNA now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer might probably lie [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130617(VS.90).aspx):

> When using this method to retrieve an
>   array from a resource that was not
>   created with a type, always use the
>   overload that accepts a type.

In true MSDN fashion, there is no further explanation.